# How to change the color of the line in ICS styled EditText

Tags: android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android-edittext, android-theme

I and using ABS together with theme holo in my application and i get EditText styled as if in ICS.

But the line color of the EditText is blue by default and for my design, i need white colored line for the EditText.

I tried changing the background, but it is not working.

Is there any way so that I can change the color from blue line to white programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211929/styling-edittext-view-with-shape-drawable-to-look-similar-to-new-holographic-the) where they are using LayerList

I used a layer-list for creating an `ICS styled edittext` as it was needed only in one place.

It works great and no issues found with varying screen resolutions. It wont accept a transparent background but works as needed for me!

**For Full Customization :**

In addition, these are other links where we can customize the ICS styles.

**1. [ActionBar Sherlock Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tabColor=33B5E5,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF,100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5,100)**

**2. [Holo Style Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/)**

**3. [Holo Theme Custom UI Libraries](http://www.androidviews.net/)**

Happy Coding..!! **:)**

Answer (score -2):

Try 
     **android:background="#00000000"** 
This only for White(or Simply hide the Bottom Line)