# EditText/AutoCompleteTextView not observing proper styling when it's in an ActionView

Tags: android

I'm trying to style my EditTexts (and AutoCompleteTextViews) a certain way so that the line is a color that I specify.  Normally, this work's just fine by following this answer: [How to change the color of the line in ICS styled EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470487/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-line-in-ics-styled-edittext).

However, it appears as though the style I define for my EditTexts is not observed when the EditText is part of an [ActionView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView) in the ActionBar menu.

I.e., I have an action view item in my menu.xml file:

```
<item
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"
/>
```

I specify the layout to be used when this is expanded with the actionLayout property, and then I have a search_layout.xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Enter Search Term"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

This EditText doesn't take on the styling that I've defined in my styles.xml (and the same thing happens if it's an AutoCompleteTextView instead).  How can I customize the style of an EditText/AutoCompleteTextView when it's a part of an ActionView?

Comment: Your code is working for me. Perhaps you have forgotten to add `style="@style/YourStyle"` to the `EditText` in `search_layout.xml`.

Comment: Or maybe you just want to remove the `collapseActionView` flag from your menu item, so the search bar is always visible.

Comment: aha, you were right! Just needed you add style="@style/EditTextAppTheme" for my specific edit text style.    Shouldn't this styling automatically be applied though without having to specify this style, since in the manifest I've set the style?  My other EditText's that aren't in an ActionView don't need the styling to be explicitly laid out.

Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As William said in the first comment on my question, the solution is to explicitly set the style on the EditText by adding `style="@style/YourStyle"` to the EditText in search_layout.xml.