# Change android EditText style from rectangular border to underscore

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-theme

In one of my activities, my EditText views used to look like this

[image]

But now they looks like this

[image]

I need help changing it back: from the rectangle to the underscore.

***BACKGROUND***

Because I needed to create a custom ActionBar, I had to change the theme of the activity in question, `YesterdayActivity`, using the following

Style:

```
<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">40dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>
```

Manifest:

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.example.YesterdayActivity"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
    </activity>
```

onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_yesterday);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.yesterday_title_bar);
…
}
```

Comment: do u want to make edittext underscore?

Comment: I just want to return to the default look like keeping my custom actionBar. If build a simple android app with an EditText, the first image is the default look, which is what I want.

Comment: For more background on the question see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605282/center-title-of-activity-in-android-action-bar

Comment: Please check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/12470487/1237656

Comment: set the theme as         ```android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"``` inside your editText

Answer (score 0):

Change your custom theme like this

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
```

because you are not using old android theme not `HoLo` which has that kinda `editTextView`

In newer versions of Android, the framework will use the `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR` feature whenever the Holo theme is selected. The framework throws the exception whenever an app calls `setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE)` and `FEATURE_ACTION_BAR` has already been set.
it crashed because Holo uses the ActionBar by default. The fix was simple. Turn the ActionBar off when using Holo

Comment: When I change parent it complains about combining custom features with other features. So the app crashes.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I don't understand your edit. What is the final code to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your style

```
<item name="android:background">#323331</item>
```

because it is the background attribute that reflects the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this. First method by changing **theme** of your application

first method:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

*See android:theme*

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ...
    ...
    </application>
```

**res/values/style.xml**

*Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar* makes underlined EditText

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Just use EditText in same way

```
<EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:hint="Email Address"
      android:inputType="textMultiLine"
      android:textSize="16dp" />
```

Second method:

Create a shape drawable with bottom stroke and set it as background of EditText

create a drawable file called **res/drawable/stroked_edittext_bg.xml** said in the below link:

[How To Create An Android Shape With Bottom Stroke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238738/android-shape-with-bottom-stroke)

```
<EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:background="@drawable/stroked_edittext_bg"
      android:hint="Email Address"
      android:inputType="textMultiLine"
      android:textSize="16dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**it can be achieve, if you change the theme for editText.**

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
```

Change back it to your default style. Or remove this line from code.

Cause the 1st image you shared that is a default Editext background.