# EditText in API Level 17

Tags: android, android-edittext

When i am using EditText in API 17 , It displays like below.

[image]

Is it possible to display the EditText as rectangular box like below in API 17 or should i use lower level API's

[image]

Comment: I think you will find an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607173/change-android-edittext-style-from-rectangular-border-to-underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in ur xml file in EditText

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:maxLength="25"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"

            />
```

Focus on this line  `android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"`

hope this will work.