# Style bottom Line in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-styles, layer-list

I need to create an android shape so that only the bottom has stroke (a dashed line). When I try the following, the stroke bisects the shape right through the center. Does anyone know how to get it right? the stroke needs to be the bottom line/border. I am using the shape as a background to a TextView. Please, never mind why I need it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#1bd4f6" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line" >
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" />

            <stroke
                android:dashGap="10px"
                android:dashWidth="10px"
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ababb2" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Why would I go see your git project for something so simple? Are you looking for hits for this project?

Comment: just out of curiosity, why are you using px to specify dash sizes?

Answer (score 341, accepted):

It's kind of a hack, but I think this is probably the best way to do it. The dashed line will always be on the bottom, regardless of the height.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#1bd4f6" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:dashGap="10px"
                android:dashWidth="10px"
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ababb2" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

### Explanation:

The second shape is transparent rectangle with a dashed outline. The key in making the border only appear along the bottom lies in the negative margins set the other sides. These negative margins "push" the dashed line outside the drawn area on those sides, leaving only the line along the bottom. One potential side-effect (which I haven't tried) is that, for views that draw outside their own bounds, the negative-margin borders may become visible.

Comment: Clever indeed. It took me some time to figure out that what makes this work is the difference in 1 dp (in absolute value) between top, right and left and the stroke width :)

Comment: This works perfectly, but could someone please supplement the answer with an explanation of the math in this (for poor souls like me and anyone else who arrives here in the days to come) :)

Comment: Works great. And you can even use a selector that points to layer-list xmls depending on state. I had to figure that one out and it works too.

Comment: Don't introduce unnecessary overdraw. I think @Anonan solution is better. Try modifying that one to your needs.

Comment: Beware of the negative margin size. When it's equal to the line thickness, it seems to be working on default device settings/ "display size" but the other edges become partially visible with display size larger than default.

Answer (score 50):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="-6dp"
        android:left="-6dp"
        android:right="-6dp"
        android:bottom="0dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#88FFFF00"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#FF000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 47):

This does the trick...

```
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#YOUR_BOTTOM_LINE_COLOR"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:bottom="1.5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#YOUR_BG_COLOR"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: There are two rectangle overlap each other and add bottom space to show another color as a line. so, you can apply this to do other way

Comment: Good answer but with redundant overdraw

Comment: and will also not work when you have colors with alpha

Answer (score 29):

I feel it is straightforward, without all this negative paddings or storks.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/main_bg_color"/>
    <item android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/bottom_bar_color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: If you don't need a special background, you can remove the `<item android:drawable="@color/main_bg_color"/>`

Comment: Works with Android 27, doesn't work with Android 19 ... didn't test other versions.

Comment: It requires API level 23 (Marshmallow).

Comment: This worked perfectly, without overlaying the bottom layer item

Answer (score 22):

**This answer is for those google searchers who want to show dotted bottom border of `EditText` like here**

[image: sample]

Create `dotted.xml` inside `drawable` folder and paste these

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/black" />    
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#030310"
                android:dashGap="5dp"
                android:dashWidth="5dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then simply set the `android:background` attribute to `dotted.xml` we just created. Your `EditText` looks like this.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some Text"
    android:background="@drawable/dotted" />
```

Answer (score 10):

Try next xml drawable code:

```
    <layer-list>
        <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#fff" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you do not need to use shape if I understood you.

If you are looking as shown in following image then use following layout.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#1bd4f6"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ababb2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Hello Android" />
 </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

play with these properties you will get result

```
    android:top="dimension"
    android:right="dimension"
    android:bottom="dimension"
    android:left="dimension"
```

try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#1bd4f6" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="20px"
    android:left="0px">
    <shape android:shape="line"  >
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" />

        <stroke
            android:dashGap="10px"
            android:dashWidth="10px"
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ababb2" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: my stroke is a dashed line

Comment: This works, the only caveat is when the view gets resized too small, the shape gets invisible

Comment: You should always be careful not to introduce unnecessary overdraw.

Answer (score 6):

**A Simple solution :**

Create a drawable file as **edittext_stroke.xml** in drawable folder.
Add the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line"
   >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" >
    </stroke>
</shape>
```

In layout file , add the drawable to edittext as

> android:drawableBottom="@drawable/edittext_stroke"

```
<EditText
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:drawableBottom="@drawable/edittext_stroke"
      />
```

Comment: In this case your line will be in the center, not bottom

Answer (score 5):

Usually for similar tasks - I created layer-list drawable like this one:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/underlineColor"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
<item android:bottom="3dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/buttonColor"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

The idea is that first you draw the rectangle with underlineColor and then on top of this one you draw another rectangle with the actual buttonColor but applying bottomPadding. It always works.

But when I needed to have buttonColor to be transparent I couldn't use the above drawable. I found one more solution

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/white_box" android:gravity="bottom"     android:height="2dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

(as you can see here the mainButtonColor is transparent and white_box is just a simple rectangle drawable with white Solid)

Answer (score 4):

use this xml change the color with your choice.

```
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/gray_500" />

            </shape>
        </item>
        <!-- CONTENT LAYER -->
        <item android:bottom="2dp" >
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

In Case if you want programmatically

```
public static Drawable getStorkLineDrawable(@ColorInt int colorStrok, int    iSize, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

{
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
    gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    gradientDrawable.setStroke(iSize, colorStrok);
    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{gradientDrawable});
    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, left, top, right, bottom);
    return layerDrawable;
}
```

call this method like

```
  Drawable yourLineDrawable=  getStorkLineDrawable(yourColor, iSize, -iSize, -iSize, -iSize, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked best for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:bottom="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#ff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Shows the line on the bottom only. You can easily change with stroke width to size you like and also update the top, left, right on the  accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

easiest way to do this is put after that view where you want bottom border

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply add -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--Minus (-) how much dp you gave in the stroke width from left right top-->
    <item android:left="-10dp" android:right="-10dp" android:top="-10dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:dashGap="10dp"
                android:dashWidth="10dp"
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
              <!--This is the main background -->
            <solid android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Preview** -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is completely transparent Edittext with transparent background.

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="-3dp" android:right="-3dp" android:left="-3dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke

            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/bottomline" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A Simple solution** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="-1dp"
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:top="-1dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="#AARRGGBB" />

            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/red"
                android:dashWidth="10dp"
                android:dashGap="12dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And finally we have something like that :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is rectangular background with bottom stroke

```xml
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="#f2f4f5" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#002f34" />
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
 
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="#f2f4f5" />
 
       </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```