# Progress Bar with a gap between left and right section

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, xml-drawable, layer-list

How do I create a progress bar with blue progress indication, grey background and *a transparent gap (black in the example) between the sections*: 
[image: progress bar with a gap between sections]

I've tried to play around with shapes, to create the left section with border only on the right. The closest example that I could find was [shape with bottom stroke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19239478/1097104), but I was unable to modify it to display the gap required in my case.

Unless I get *shape* to work, I might end up using `setSecondaryProgress()` in code.

Comment: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html

Comment: use setProgressDrawable,  you will need to create your custom Drawable in the code as what you want cannot be done in xml, you will need to override onLevelChange and call invalidateSelf

Comment: if you are unsure how it works see ClipDrawable sources,,  ClipDrawable is a part of std progress Drawable

Comment: @pskink, I followed your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21060826/1097104. With some adaptations I can fit it for my needs. If you could add an answer to this question also, I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use setProgressDrawable, you will need to create your custom Drawable in the code as what you want cannot be done in xml, you will need to override onLevelChange and call invalidateSelf, see [Custom ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052063/custom-progressbar/21060826#21060826) for a sample implementation