# Add a border at the end of a listview in a two listview fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

As the title says, I have a fragment with two list views and i want to add a border at the end of the second list view. I know that this is usally achieved in the xml writing:

```
android:paddingBottom="50dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

And when i use only one listView it works perfectly but not with two i don't know why. 
I have tried adding a white layout in the getView of my baseAdapter but the problem is that I want to manage long clicks i for that I use :

```
listViewSin.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
listViewSin.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {...});
```

And in this method I can't know the kind of view that is clicked before the menu is created, so i don't want to add a new view.

The layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/sin"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/android"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            />


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/hechos"
            android:textColor="#A2A2A2"
            android:id="@+id/ios"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#A2A2A2"
            />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="#A2A2A2"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="80dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/tareas_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@drawable/add"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />
```

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi added

Comment: Please! Nested scrollable Views are a **terrible** design! And you don't need the Relative or the LinearLayout - depending on which one you choose (I'd choose the RelativeLayout).

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi then what should i do? (I'm kind of new in android)

Comment: First learn how Views **relate** to each other in a RelativeLayout. Then learn about *margins*. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Define a shape drawable in a way similar to what's explained here:

[Android border bottom for custom view not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279821/android-border-bottom-for-custom-view-not-working)

Set the rectangle's color to your `ListView's` background color, and the stroke's color to your desired bottom border color. Then in xml, in your `ListView` element background attribute, reference the shape with @drawable/...