# How to change the color of line at the bottom in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I know this question has been asked before but that solution are not working in my case. I want to change edit text bottom line color and tried the solution from other links to add this line to theme in styles.xml

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
```

but somehow this is not working in my case. I tried changing base theme but still not working for me.
And I want to do this with all editext in my app, not just only one.
Are there any other ways of doing it??

Comment: are you using appcompact activity??

Comment: Check #Rohit Heera's answer

Comment: Plz post your layout and style files code

Answer (score 3):

Edit Style.xml under values folder.

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#c5c5c5</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I have written that's not working . Why not you read the question carefully

Comment: You dint add colorControlActivated and colorControlHighlight?

Comment: I don't want them so I didn't added them

Comment: I am able to change activated color but somehow Normal is not working

Answer (score 1):

create a file edittextborder.xml in drawable folder  and write

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />


            </shape></item>

    </selector>
```

and Set this file as:

```
android:background="@drawable/edittextborder"
```

in editText.

Comment: I don't want it on selecting edit text . I want it to be white by default

Comment: yes it make your edittext bydefault it is not on selection

Comment: ok let me try then I will tell

Comment: Just try once it will definately solve your problem

Comment: this is filling whole editext with color provided in the shape

Comment: you set the transparentcolor instead of white

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99377/discussion-between-vivek-mishra-and-rohit-heera).

Answer (score 1):

This can be changed in xml by using:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
```

Comment: tint requires minimum android version 21

Comment: you want to bottom line same color when its not focus?

Comment: problem is now solved but as you are asking. As activity opens all editext bottom line color were black and were changing to white when focused.White part was desired behaviour but I wanted to change color when not focused

Answer (score 0):

I preferred to use 9 patch images for edit text custom color. 
[Android 9 patch generator online](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

This is awesome online tool generator for all widgets.[Android Holo colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

generate and download for every dpi folder. and apply it using background.

Answer (score 0):

Solution follows as below-

1. I want u to visit [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/).
2. Provide a Theme name and select a color u want.
3. Select the components u want to change the color. In ur case its Edittext.
4. Finally click on Download Zip.
5. Extract the Zip and use it in ur proj.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_to"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder" //.xml file for edittext
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="Text_to"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**customborder.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Comment: is your problem solved ? @
Vivek Mishra

Comment: no this also creates complete border all sides

Answer (score 0):

Using Rohit's answer and a hack provided from this link [Android Bottom Stroke only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238738/android-shape-with-bottom-stroke).I was able to achieve my desired behaviour. Here is the code for drawable folder file.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke

                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```