# Custom shape drawable android(lines only above and below a view)

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-drawable, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

> **I want two white lines -one on top of the view ,and the other one on
>   the bottom the view!!!**

**no left and right borders!!!!!**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
    <stroke android:width="0.1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

I get a rectangle shaped view with white border,and transparent background.

**But i want only the top and bottom lines of rectangle ,and not left and right lines of rectangle .**

I want a view with border only on top and bottom,that will seem like sandwiched between two thin lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android shape with bottom stroke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238738/android-shape-with-bottom-stroke)

Comment: 0X0nosugar is wright, there is no natural shape with single stroke lines, you´ll have to do some layerList layout....

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<layer-list>`. Check this below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Border -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="COLOR_OF_BORDER" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Rest of the drawable -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="COLOR_OF_REST" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```